# Android studio 2021.2.1 ADB and Emulator Issue

Tags: android-studio, adb, android-emulator

I'm trying to run my react-native project on android studio 2021.2.1 (Latest) on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
When I execute the command

```
yarn run android
```

It throws me this error:

```
info JS server already running.
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Emulator exited before boot..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
```

and Thus, the execution gets failed.

I've followed React Native's [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)
 accordingly. Here are the procedures:

Android SDK [Screenshot] :

[Android SDK With Location Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JK8b.png)

If you see, my **Android SDK Location** is: ***/home/maruf/Android/Sdk***

SDK Tools are [Screenshot] :

[SDK Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K1BA.png)

Lastly, the ***.bash_profile*** file codes are:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$HOME/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
```

[Screenshot] :

[.bash_profile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNixn.png)

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? I'm really stuck man.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

1. `/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found`

Because I didn't have adb installed on my machine.

`sudo apt install adb`

2. Had to create a **local.properties** and add
   `sdk.dir = /home/maruf/Android/Sdk`. Although, I'd like to ask for a solution on how to avoid this file.